# Issues with conditions ignoring the boundary's set by if statements but still recognizing them

Tags: python

I've been making a simple program where you get assigned 10 random numbers and are asked to guess whether the next number is higher or lower.

I'm having issues with my program detecting when the answer is wrong as it just lets incorrect guesses go by. I didn't have this issue until recently when I had to fix a bug where the game just wouldn't continue at random times.

I don't know what to do to fix it since I've exhausted my options. Any help is appreciated.

```
from random import randint

print("1. This game is for a single player.")
print()
print("2. At the start, the program randomly generates a list of 10 numbers to"
      "represent playing cards of a single suit.")
print()
print("3. The first card is flipped, and the player is asked to guess whether"
      "the next card is higher or lower than the known flipped card.")
print()
print("4. If the player guesses correctly, they guess the next card in the"
      "sequence.")
print()
print("5. If the player’s guess is incorrect at any point along the sequence, "
      "they lose the game.")
print()
print("6. If the player correctly guesses all cards, they win the game.")
print()

#Number Generation--------------------------------------------------------------
numblist = []

while len(numblist) < 10:
    numb = randint(1, 10)
    if numb not in numblist:
        numblist.append(numb)
#Board--------------------------------------------------------------------------
turn = 0 
boardline = []
numblist.append(0)
boardline.append(numblist[turn])
print(boardline)
#Game---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Prints out list to check for H or L
print(numblist)

# Variable Setup
turn = 1
selectedch = 0
gamenotbroken = True
guesswrong = False
choicevalid = False
gameactive = True

print("Will the next value be Higher (H) or Lower (L)? ")
while gameactive == True:
    if len(boardline) > 9:
        print("You have won!!")
        gameactive = False
        choicevalid = False
        
    elif guesswrong == True:
        print("You lost try again")
        gameactive = False
        choicevalid = False
        
    if gamenotbroken == True:
        choice = input("Guess: ")
        if choice.lower() not in ['h', 'higher', 'l', 'lower']:
            print("Not a valid option")
        else:
            choicevalid = True
        
        if choicevalid == True:
            if choice in ['h', 'higher'] and  selectedch == 0:
                if numblist[turn] > numblist[turn + 1]:
                    print("It was higher")
                    choicevalid = False
                    gameactive = True
                    selectedch = 1
                    
            if numblist[turn] < numblist[turn + 1] and selectedch == 1:
                guesswrong = True
                                    
            if choice in ['l', 'lower'] and selectedch == 0:
                if numblist[turn] < numblist[turn + 1]:
                    print("It was lower")
                    choicevalid = False
                    gameactive = True
                    selectedch = 2
                    
            if numblist[turn] > numblist[turn + 1] and selectedch == 2:
                guesswrong = True
                        
                        
        print("Will the next value be Higher (H) or Lower (L)? ")
        boardline.append(numblist[turn])
        print(boardline)
        turn = turn + 1
        print("Turn", turn)
        selectedch = 0 
            
        #Debug
        #print("GMATV: ", gameactive)
        #print("CHVLD: ", choicevalid)
        #print("GUWRN: ", guesswrong)
```

Comment: You seem to be starting from the second card: ```turn = 1``` is set before the loop begins. Maybe you're actually checking for the card after the one you want by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the main problem with the code is that boardline (check if the guess was right) has the first guessable number (you only appended the first one) but not the rest (the +1 just makes it loop around back to the same number) so either switch the

`boardline.append(numblist[turn])` to `boardline = numblist`

or move the `boardline.append(numblist[turn])` you have at the bottom to the top of the loop. Also turn should be equal to 0 (the first element in the list is the 0th element)

You also seem to have a lot of floating variables (you don't need a guesswrong and choice valid variable) so you might want to clean that up.

Finally avoid empty print statement (it's not bad but it makes stuff messy), to add a new line, you can just add \n to the end of the string so like print("text\n")